# how to create electronic switch cut off PV from MPPT charger when no battery connection

Tags: solar-cell, charger, mppt

MPPT chargers are sensitive if PV is connected without battery connection. MPPT will be destroyed.
So I want put electronic switch on MPPT PV input in a relation with battery voltage
[image].
No voltage on battery input no connection to PV input. PV current can be up to 40A,150V. And battery voltage from 10V to 30V. I can put relay but there is no space in MPPT and relay consume more power.
Can somebody advise mosfet solution for such idea. Thanks, and sorry for to big jpg.

Comment: I just have a manual switch to the pv. But why would the batteries become disconnected? Stolen??

Comment: You can open circuit OR SHORT CIRCUIT the PV panel if the battery is absent. SC panel provides no power (only current). Relay contact (or MOSFET) could be normally on and switched OFF by battery voltage.

Comment: My idea is just to protect MPPT when I forget to disconnect PV or if is something wrong with battery. I already burn one of my MPPT.